# How to fix DataGridView RowHeader text wrapping problem?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to decrease the height of `DataGridView` rows to allow showing as much of theme. But all my best effort produces the following result:

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9572/datagridview.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9572/datagridview.png)

These are the settings used for the `RowHeaderDefaultCellStyle`:

```
aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray
aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Format = "X4"    
aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False
```

Look at the `RowHeaders`, the text is truncated and ugly.

Do you have any idea how can I improve it, **without reducing the font size or increasing the height of the row**?

Answer (score 1):

You want to reduce the [Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle_members.aspx) in the cell.

Comment: I set the Padding to 0, nothing changes. aGrid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(0)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to increase the row height.

```
 aGrid.RowTemplate.Height = 15
```